# Detect error of a running process?

Tags: 12.04, process, error-handling

I have a to execute a process that sometimes produces an error. However every time it produces that error, it doesn't exit the process.

```
aneesh@nb-14:~$ emulator -no-boot-anim -avd Andreud
Emulator ERROR: Unable to load VM from snapshot. The snapshot file was saved for a
different hardware configuration
^Z
aneesh@nb-14:~$ emulator -no-boot-anim -avd Andreud
```

On success the cursor is at the beginning of the second line above and the emulator error doesn't show up. On failure it shows the error but I am forced to stop it. The commands might seem to show that this question is off-topic.

However my question is how (via a command) to detect this error while this process is still running and if yes kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the emulator in the background, sending all of its output to a temporary file

```
emulator -no-boot-anim -avd Andreud &>/tmp/emulator-output &
```

Then get the PID of the recently launched process, and store it in a variable called EMULATORPID

```
EMULATORPID=$!
```

Then, while the emulator is still running, watch the output file for the error, and when it is found, kill the process by PID:

```
while ps -p$EMULATORPID ; do
   grep "Emulator ERROR" /tmp/emulator-output && kill $EMULATORPID
done
```

To satisfy the additional requirement of quitting the while loop after five seconds, you could set a counter, increment it each loop, and add a delay of one section to each iteration like so:

```
  CTR=0
  while ps -p$EMULATORPID &&  [ $CTR -lt 5 ]  ; do
     grep "Emulator ERROR" /tmp/emulator-output && kill $EMULATORPID
     sleep 1s;
     CTR=$[CTR+1] 
  done
```

Comment: Is it `-p$EMULATORPID ; ... ` or `-p $EMULATORPID ; ... `. (space in between?)

Comment: Currently a process is running I want to kill it and start fresh. I gave the command `kill $!`. It teaches me this:
`kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`
What must I do?

Comment: ps works with or without a space between the ``-p`` and the pid. If you run ``kill $!`` and you get a usage message, then ``$!`` is probably not defined. You can check that by echoing it, like ``echo $!`` . $! is only defined within the specific terminal from which you have launched another process, so you must run all of the commands I listed in order, in the same terminal session.

Comment: Thanks. However I have an additional requirement. Edited the question.

Comment: I've edited my answer.